# How to find the n'th index path in tableview in iOS?

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a tableview with multiple sections, each section has more than one row, but the number of rows in sections is not equal, like this

```
first 1
"row 1.1"

second 2
"row 2.1"
"row 2.2"
"row 2.3"----->

second 3
"row 3.1"
"row 3.2"
"row 3.3"
"row 3.4"
"row 3.5"
"row 3.6"
```

I want to get the 4th element in the tableview which is "row 2.3"
Its index path is [1, 2]
How should I get this index path?

My solution was to find "row 2.3" in tableview and then find its indexPath. Is there any other way to get the nth element index path?

Comment: Are you need to get always 2.3 item or anything which placed on 4th place of tableView

Comment: read it out from your _model_ probably...?

Comment: @PravinTate no anything in the 4th place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over the sections, subtract the number of rows in
the current section from the given index, until the index is a valid row number in the current  section. Something like this (untested):

```
extension UITableView {
    func indexPath(forIndex index: Int) -> IndexPath? {
        var row = index
        var section = 0
        while section < self.numberOfSections && row >= self.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
            row -= self.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
            section += 1
        }
        if section < self.numberOfSections {
            return IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

(The given index is assumed to be zero-based, i.e. `tableView.indexPath(forIndex: 0)` returns the first valid index path 
of the table view.)

Comment: also may be you need to set **var row = index - 1**

Comment: @Sh_Khan: That depends how you count. I would always use index=0 for the first table view cell.

Comment: the op gives 1-based value

Comment: @Sh_Khan: You are right, therefore I have clarified that here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var neededNumber = 5 - 1 // 5th element

var index:IndexPath?

for sec in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {

    if neededNumber < tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: sec) {

        index = IndexPath(row: neededNumber, section: sec)

        break
    }
    else
    {
        neededNumber -= tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: sec)
    }

 }

if let myIndex = index {

    print(myIndex)

}
```

Comment: `<=` should probably be `<`, and you should exit the loop if a matching section is found, otherwise `index` can be overwritten later.

Answer (score 1):

```
func indexPath(for index: Int) -> IndexPath? {
    var counter = 0
    for sectionIndex in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
        for rowIndex in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: sectionIndex) {
            if index == counter {
                return IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: sectionIndex)
            }
            counter += 1
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```